# Can a Redis instance be configured to NOT overwrite old snapshots?

Tags: database, github, redis

Currently I am using the `redis.conf` file to provide the fixed directory and filename to my instance to save the redis `dump.rdb` snapshot.

My intention is to compare two redis snapshots taken at different times.
But Redis rewrites over the old dump file after creating the new one.

I checked the redis repo on github and found the `rdb.c` file, which has the code that executes the `SAVE` commands and rewrites over old snapshots.

Before messing with code(since i'm not an experienced developer), I wanted to ask if there is a better way to save snapshots taken at different times? Or if I could just save the last 2 snapshots at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [incron](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/how-use-incron-monitor-important-files-and-folders/) to watch the dump directory and execute a script

```
sudo apt-get install incron
echo "redis" >> /etc/incron.allow

export EDITOR=vi
incrontab -e

/path/where/you/dump/files IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN_CREATE,IN_DELETE /bin/copy_snapshot
```

then create a /bin/copy_snapshot script file rename it with a date or something and make sure there are X number of copies